# Importing Static Functions Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to import a static class function into my main.js file but using the function after compiling with tsc I get:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'router' of undefined
> at Object. (path/to/main.js:36:27)>

I have tried to assign it a type with no luck as well as using different methods of importing again with no luck...

I feel as if the answer is simple but cant seem to locate it in the TS docs and I'm just banging my head at this point.

Here is the class I am trying to export.

> Session.ts

```
export class Session {

    //Class Members

   constructor() {
      //Big constructor lots of this. = 
   };

   //Creating the functions needed

   logOut() {
      delete Session.ssnsById[this.id];
      delete Session.ssnsByCookie[this.authToken];
   };

static router = function (req: Request, res: Response, next: Function) {
      var cookie = req.cookies[Session.cookieName];
      var session = cookie && Session.ssnsByCookie[cookie];

      if (session) {
         // If the session was last used more than |duration| mS ago..
         if (session.lastUsed < new Date().getTime() - Session.duration)
            session.logOut();
         else {
            req.session = session;
         }
      }
      next();
   };
}

module.exports = Session;
```

> Importing into my main.ts

```
import { Session } from "./Session";


// Set up Session on req if available
app.use(Session.router); //<--
```

After running tsc we get built/main.js

```
const Session_1 = require("./Session");

// Set up Session on req if available
app.use(Session_1.Session.router); //<-This line throws the error.
```

Lastly here is my tsconfig.json used to compile

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
       "module": "commonjs",
       "esModuleInterop": true,
       "target": "es6",
       "noImplicitAny": true,
       "noImplicitThis": true,
       "moduleResolution": "node",
       "sourceMap": false,
       "baseUrl": ".",
       "outDir": "built",
       "paths": {
           "*": [
               "node_modules/*"
           ]
       }
   },
   "include": [
       "Src/**/*"
   ]
}
```

Comment: try remove `module.exports = Session;` line.

Comment: This seemed to do the trick! Than you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: Please remove module.exports = Session;

2: Add a new file name 'custom.d.ts' in the root directory and add the following:

```
import { Session } from "./Session";

declare module 'express-serve-static-core' {
    interface Request {
        router?: typeof Session['router'],
    }
}
```

3: Do this in the file where you imported Session class.

```
import {Request, Response, NextFunction} from 'express';
import { Session } from "./Session";


// Set up Session on req if available
app.use((req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
   req.router = Session.router;
   next();
});
```

You will have your router on the req :)

Answer (score 0):

Removing module.exports = Session; Cleared the problem for me!